# How to add additional variables in yii url

Tags: yii

I'm working with Yii framework and i'm trying to implement "create pdf" button on all sorts of different url's.
My first plan was to simply add variable to url where "create pdf" button links:

```
'url' => Yii::app()->request->getUrl().'&pdf=true',
```

And it works fine on all links except when i enter directly to site like: www.example.com. In that case there is no index.php in url so button link is unusable as it looks like this:

www.example.com/&pdf=true

Is there Yii way to append variables to url or I need to do manual checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add your parameter(s) to the original parameters with the `CMap::mergeArray($_GET, array('pdf' => 'true'))`

and use the Yii::app()->createUrl or your Controller's createUrl function:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#createUrl-detail

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. It looks like too "common" thing not to be implemented into Yii, i just didnt know where to look for. Thanks. It's working great!

Answer (score 2):

create your links like this :

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('controllerName/actionName', array('number' => 2, 'name'=>'john'));

//or this if you want it with http:://
Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('controllerName/actionName', array('number' => 2, 'name'=>'john'));
```

Comment: Great Compatriot :) Please modify your answer with adding createAbsoluteUrl() and its detail for questioner if it's possible. Thanks